# Game Design: How to determine dynamic visual distance between players with good performance?

Tags: python, performance, server

I'm designing a game server and need to determine which players someone can see depending on their x,y coordinates on the map (you can only see players within x distance). I have the idea to create a matrix as below and iterate over every entry each tick and calculate the relative distance, and then determine which players you can see based on that (if within x distance)

The issue is that this is O(n²) – Quadratic Time. Is it possible to achieve my goal with greater performance? O(n) would be fine.

I should mention that the distance at which players can see each other is not constant. Just because two players are within the same 'grid', it doesn't mean they can necessarily see each other due to variable vision distance.

This is more of a theory question, but I'm writing it in Python if it matters.

```
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|                  | player1: 100,200 | player2: 300,400 | player3: 500,600 |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| player1: 100,200 | 0                | x                | x                |
| player2: 300,400 | x                | 0                | x                |
| player3: 500,600 | x                | x                | 0                |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: This is frequent basic problem called [nearest neighbor search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search). The standard way to solve it is to use kd-tree (or quad-tree, or other similar data structure). An example of [Python implementation of BallTree is available in SciPy](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html). The resulting running time complexity is `O(n log n)`. AFAIK, this is the optimal one for exact solutions.